# Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery in ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a working ASP.NET core web application that utilizes javascript to call a controller method. However, the controller method is currently not protected from cross-site request forgery.

My current controller method is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public async Task CallMe(string destination, string callIndex, string fromNumber)
{
    var userLogin = HttpContext.Session.Get<UserLogin>("userLogin");

    if (userLogin != null)
    {
        var tokenModel = await GetSessionToken();
        ...
    }
}
```

The corresponding javascript in my CSHTML page is as follows:

```
...
$.post("@Url.Action("CallMe")", { destination: destination, callIndex: callIndex, fromNumber: fromNumber });
```

After adding the antiforgery token to the page as recommended by the Microsoft article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript).

My controller is the same except for the [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task CallMe(string destination, string callIndex, string fromNumber)
{
    var userLogin = HttpContext.Session.Get<UserLogin>("userLogin");

    if (userLogin != null)
    {
        var tokenModel = await GetSessionToken();
        ...
    }
}
```

My updated javascript call is as follows:

```
var data = { destination: destination, callIndex: callIndex, fromNumber: fromNumber };

fetch("@Url.Action("CallMe")", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'RequestVerificationToken':
            document.getElementById("RequestVerificationToken").value
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

The javascript calls the method as expected; however, all parameters are null. In Fiddler, I've able to verify the header values are correct and the body is as follows:

```
{ "destination": "xxx", "callIndex": "xxx_idx", "fromNumber": "xxxx" }
```

What else needs to be added to pass the values correctly?

Comment: Found this post discussing a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542328/passing-multiple-post-parameters-in-asp-net-core-controller

Comment: Have your problem been sovled? There are three ways to solve the problem:1. add parameters in the url: `var url = /Controllername/CallMe?destination=aa&callIndex=vv&fromNumber=dd` 2.You can create a model contains these parameters then use `[FromBody]` , 3. use ajax to pass values as your founded post.